# how to keep rows based on first digit of elements in r ?

Tags: r

I have the following data.frame

```
crime<-c(71040,142320,71013,71013,72113)
coded.month<-c("2018-10","2018-10","2018-10","2018-10","2018-10")
df<-data.frame(coded.month,crime)
  coded.month  crime
1     2018-10  71040
2     2018-10 142320
3     2018-10  71013
4     2018-10  71013
5     2018-10  72113
```

Bascially, I want to isolate all the rows where the first digit of crime is `7` so that I get the following

```
  coded.month  crime
1     2018-10  71040
3     2018-10  71013
4     2018-10  71013
5     2018-10  72113
```

how do I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `substr`:

```
df[substr(df$crime, 0, 1) == 7, ]
#   coded.month crime
# 1     2018-10 71040
# 3     2018-10 71013
# 4     2018-10 71013
# 5     2018-10 72113
```

Answer (score 2):

using `startsWith` :

```
subset(df, startsWith(as.character(crime),"7"))
#   coded.month crime
# 1     2018-10 71040
# 3     2018-10 71013
# 4     2018-10 71013
# 5     2018-10 72113
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `%/%`

```
df[df$crime%/% 10000 == 7, ]
#    coded.month crime
#1     2018-10 71040
#3     2018-10 71013
#4     2018-10 71013
#5     2018-10 72113
```

Answer (score 0):

This also involves converting values (implicitly) to strings, but it works:

```
 df[grep("^7", df$crime), ]
```

Edit: a purely numerical solution:

```
df[floor(df$crime /  10^floor(log10(df$crime))) == 7, ]
```

Answer (score 0):

By defining a new dataframe using `grepl()` to match only those `df$crime`values that start with "7":

```
df_new <- df[grepl("^7", df$crime, perl = T),]
df_new
  coded.month crime
1     2018-10 71040
3     2018-10 71013
4     2018-10 71013
5     2018-10 72113
```